# Simulating a four transistor audio amplifier circuit in LTspice

Tags: amplifier, ltspice, spice

I'm designing a four transistor audio amplifier circuit.

[image]

I simulated it in LTspice. I replaced the BC547 with a TIP142 and the BC557 with a TIP147.

[image]

1. Collector
2. Base
3. Emitter

When run mode V out is not amplified.
[image],

What is the problem here?

Comment: Are you really feeding a 12 V peak signal in that 9 V powered amplifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BC547](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/BC547-190204.pdf) and the [BC557](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A100/BC556_BC557_BC558-CDIL.pdf) are small signal transistors.  The [TIP142](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tip142.pdf) and the [TIP147](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tip147.pdf) are Darlington power transistors.

The input signal level and the biasing for the small signal transistors won't work with the Darlington power transistors.

Comment: What parameters in the datasheet can distinguish them?

Comment: Start with "VBE (on)."  0.7V for the BC parts, about 3V for the TIP parts.

Comment: LTspice should have the BC parts.  Try your circuit using the proper components first.  See if that works (make sure you have drawn the circuit correctly.)  Once the circuit works as designed, you can swap out the transistors to see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it now.

Comment: @MrCR For better reading the schematic, just use the already available symbol for transistor, it will make your (and others') life easier. If it's not a `.model` then change `QN` or `QP` to `X` (use `Ctrl+RClick`).

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWt4d.png) is how it looks like with the built-in transistors.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  What is your DC bias current of Q3 &Q4?

Comment: @Antonio51 133u Q4 and 166u Q3, but I haven't even given it more than the thought of reconstructing it for the purpose of showing it to the OP -- the schematic is as cheap as they come (547 & 8 Ohm speaker?). I probably wouldn't use this to save my life and, honestly, I'm surprised it manages to even avoid cross-over distortion.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I asked because my DC current levels are "114 mA" on a 10 Ohm load ?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen why my circuit has no inductor, Vout is not amplifying? Is the circuit in my question wrong? https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpLRf.png

Comment: I made a "miss" ... 114 mA is the emitter current of Q3 & Q4.

Comment: @MrCR No load means no current. My load mimics a speaker, but even a plain resistor will do. But not in real life: the 547 are 100 mA transistors, even with 2 V peak output you risk frying them. This is a good example of why simulators are good to have: you realize the inefficiency of the circuit *and* why it is so, without spending money on breadboards (but simulators *do not replace* the breadboards).

Comment: @Antonio51 Did you mean the DC bias or the current with signal? Maybe you missed, or misplaced a connection?

Comment: DC bias. I checked sometimes ... No schematic errors,... I guess.

Comment: Ok. If R7 (op picture = 100k) then Ic of Q3 & Q4 more reasonable @ 1.5 mA ???

Comment: @Antonio51 Can you post a screenshot? Even if the `.model`s are different, I doubt they would account for such a difference.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  here are two pictures made with DC Dynamic (resistor 10k & 100k and file.cir for microcap v12). https://www.dropbox.com/s/bja1hkddefjczk5/BJT%20push-pull%20v000.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Antonio51 Your supply is 15 V, not 9 V, and with a 10 Ohm load LTspice says ~183 mA, but that's with the built-in 5x7B (bf=344/294). With a 5x7A model from a quick search (bf=227/178) it shows 122 mA. Using 9 V with these it shows 36/76 uA.

Comment: Ok. I did lack the power supply :-( ... Now 19 uA and 51 uA.